# EpiServer - secondary category functionality

Tags: episerver

I would like to add another property like categories in EpiServer. I am already using the categories for something, but I need the same type of functionality for something else. To be able to maintain a list of options in the CMS and give the Editor the possibility to attach them to a block / page. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you could just add another property of type **PropertyCategory**: http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/9/A942B3E7

It will essentially give you another category selector, in addition to the built-in one.

Comment: I want to be able to create a new category list along side the standard one with different categories in settings and have a selector for these on my pages. If that can be done with what you say, could you elaborate a bit on what I should be doing.